# how to display dynamic text in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Im trying to display text but that isnt working.

I create a dynamic text on the stage and assign it an instance '_test'. Then i have the following code _test.text = "hello";

When the code is ran, 'e' is displayed. Why?what am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you embedded the font in the textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sound if it you're facing a font embedding issue, try setting the font to `_sans` and see if that fixes it! If yes, then you just have to make sure that you're embedding all the glyphs you need from your custom font.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem! its odd because the font i was using is new times roman :o

Comment: You're welcome :) Please mark the answer as accepted with the little tick mark on the left so that others finding this question will know what was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Is your textbox too small in width & the text is getting hidden???

Is the text getting hidden due to the current font??

Have you set the textbox text to 'e' at some other part of the code??